# iPhone problems with PHP sessions

Tags: php, ios, iphone, session

This is something that I in practice so far I have not seen before.

I made a web app which works beautifully on all devices (so far I was thinking). Last week I received a few complaints that one part of the application does not work. Maybe I've reviewed over 100 times my code and I have not found a mistake and error behavior is that at one point the session expires or is just is not setup - which is not possible. The system was tested on a pile of users.

Today I received a response from a client that uses the iPhone 5. And really happens is that sessions are not working properly.

I use this session to force the user to open the pages in the order and that there is no possibility of jumping from page to page. If the user tries to skip the page, just go back to the beginning and need to re-start the process.

On the iPhone during the process returns me to the start and stop. It does not allow you to go to level 1 just returning back until you clear you cache.

This error happen randomly anywhere in process.

-To mention, I sessions not deleted until the user reache the end.

Is it possible that the iPhone has a problem with their browser or is error on my side?

Thanks!

Comment: if cookies are disabled php sessions wont work you should as him if his browser allow cookies

Comment: If you are using ajax you should check http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php to force session write before the page stop loading

Comment: Is not AJAX, Cookies is enabled on browser I check that. You need to be login and I use cookie for login. Is enabled in browser but can I check cookie data in iPhone browser?

Comment: you can use alerts alert(document.cookie);

Comment: or you can try debuging using chrome in iphone mod it not 100% the same but it will be great if you get the same error in this mode, it will be very easy to debug

Comment: Best part is safari is default browser of iphone so you have to run safari in iphone mode that works exactly iphone safari does. best way to debug your app.

Comment: @NeerajKumar - I try to simulate on PC and can't generate same error.

Comment: @IvijanStefanStipić You can use this website as iphone simulator http://transmog.net/iphone-simulator/ there are seevral online iphone simulators on which you can test the same.

Comment: @NeerajKumar this is goot to test design but AJAX not work on this simulator. I find few simulators too but not work wery well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is what that solved the same problem i was facing earliar. May this will help..**
the session problems for login page might occur because the url you are opening in the browser are not unique. for example If say you are creating a login page for your website, and you have created sessions successfully. Now, if you are logging in from url say http://geekzgarage.com then your session is limited to this url only. If you again open the above url like http://www.geekzgarage.com (note www. in both urls), then you will see that you are not logged in. So please be sure that your webpage is opening always in single type of url. either with www. or without www.

Comment: Yes. I know about that. Session looks WWW like subdomain. I have not yet thought about that - I need to check. Thanks!

Comment: @IvijanStefanStipić If that solved your issue,  you should accept the answer.